# How to prevent Kendo Panelbar from collapsing when I click button which is places on the panelbar itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-panelbar

I have a button which is placed on Kendo Panelbar. I was writing a jQuery function so that when user clicks on the button panelbar does not collapse. Other logic that I put on is that there is no post-back when button is clicked. I can't get this to work. Help appreciated ! :) Here is the code snippet.

```
$("#panelBarCarDetails").kendoPanelBar({
        expandMode: "multiple"

        $('#btnTakeOwnership').click(function (e) {
            if (e.target) {
                e.preventDefault();

            }             
          });
```

Comment: That inner code shouldn't be there, you are defining the panelBar in it, you can't place that function there, it must be outside

Comment: do you think ready function would be a good place for it ?

Comment: No, it may be independent. Place it [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/3hmfqfuv/)

Comment: Thanks ! ya that makes sense for this function to be independent.

Comment: Do you know @chiapa how do preventDefault of the Kendo PanelBar when button click ? I tried this code but it did not work. http://jsfiddle.net/vjjt2L0p/

Comment: That code can never work, give me a sec. The Kendo UI demos page is unavailable now. What have you got, a panelBar with a button in it? And if you click the button, the panelBar collapses?

Comment: I have got a Kendo PanelBar. On it I have a button and I dont want the panelbar collapse/expand when user clicks on this button. User can click on panelbar anywhere but the button and panelbar will behave like expected.

Comment: You mean you have something [like this](http://dojo.telerik.com/@joaosimoes/ERufI)?

Comment: Not really. So in your example suppose lets say I want to put a button on  Projects panelbar. So I would placed it somewhere like this: <li>
                    Projects
                   <button>whats up?</button> What would we have  to do so that when someone clicks on button whats up the Projects panelbar would not expand or collapse. Does that make sense ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85318/discussion-between-chiapa-and-heretolearn).

Comment: Just saw this and I replied you in chat window!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find a solution for your problem by creating a boolean variable that represents the possibility to expand or collapse the panelBar. When you click the button, it will "lock" the panel.

Then, on expand or collapse events, it will check this variable's value and `preventDefault` or not depending on it.

Here's a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nm4c4m4m/)**

```js
var canExpandCollapse = true;
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#panelbar").kendoPanelBar({
         expandMode: "multiple",
         collapse: cancelExpandCollapse,
         expand: cancelExpandCollapse
     });
 });

 function cancelExpandCollapse(e) {
     if (!canExpandCollapse) {
         e.preventDefault();
         canExpandCollapse = true;
     }
 }

 $("#wu").click(function (e) {
     canExpandCollapse = false;
 });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.805/styles/kendo.common-fiori.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.805/styles/kendo.fiori.min.css" />

    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.805/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.805/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div id="example">
    <ul id="panelbar">
        <li> <span class="k-link k-state-selected">My Teammates</span>

            <br/>
            <p>Some trash here</p>
            <p>Some trash here</p>
            <br/>
            <br/>
        </li>
        <li id="">Projects
            <button id="wu">Click me, I won't expand/collapse</button>
            <ul>
                <li>New Business Plan</li>
                <li>Sales Forecasts
                    <ul>
                        <li>Q1 Forecast</li>
                        <li>Q2 Forecast</li>
                        <li>Q3 Forecast</li>
                        <li>Q4 Forecast</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Sales Reports</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Programs
            <ul>
                <li>Monday</li>
                <li>Tuesday</li>
                <li>Wednesday</li>
                <li>Thursday</li>
                <li>Friday</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Communication</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks a lot for working through this with me :). It works like charm !

Comment: Have you tried to just put return false in button click function? like [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sofqcdpk/)

Comment: @LukaszSalamon, could you show how? The link you posted has the same code as the solution

Answer (score 3):

Return `false` form your button click event handler function.

```
$('#btnTakeOwnership').click(function (e) {
        if (e.target) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }             
        return false;
      });
```

Changed [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8vbp5cjw/) from chiapas answer