# How do you toggle a checkbox on a Kendo UI PanelBar that can expand or collapse?

Tags: checkbox, kendo-ui, kendo-panelbar

I am trying to make a panel bar with several expandable options with checkboxes at each level. The problem I am running into is that if you click on a checkbox that is part of an expandable panel, the checkbox does not toggle. Below is a simplified example that shows the problem. In the example below it is impossible to toggle the checkbox for *Main 1*

```js
const panelBarTemplate = `
    <span class='k-state-default'>
        <span>#: item.text #</span>
        <input type='checkbox'
            id=#: item.id #
            class='k-checkbox'
            # if (item.isVisible) { #checked='checked'# } # />
        # var ItemCheckboxLabelClass = "k-checkbox-label" #
        # if (item.items) { ItemCheckboxLabelClass = "k-checkbox-label expandable-item" } #
        <label class="#: ItemCheckboxLabelClass #" for=#: item.id # />
    </span>
`;

var canExpandCollapse = true;

$('#side-bar-panel').kendoPanelBar({
  template: panelBarTemplate,
  dataSource: [{
    text: 'Main 1',
    id: 'Main1',
    isVisible: true,
    expanded: true,
    items: [{
      text: 'Sub 1',
      id: 'Sub1',
      isVisible: true
    }, {
      text: 'Sub 2',
      id: 'Sub2',
      isVisible: false
    }]
  }],
  dataBound: function() {
    $('.expandable-item').click(function() {
      canExpandCollapse = false;
    });
  },
  expand: cancelExpandCollapse,
  collapse: cancelExpandCollapse
});

function cancelExpandCollapse(e) {
  if (!canExpandCollapse) {
    e.preventDefault();
    canExpandCollapse = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.flat.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<ul id="side-bar-panel">
</ul>
```

I found a solution for preventing expanding and collapsing when clicking on the checkbox here https://stackoverflow.com/a/31879672/4708150, but even though expanding and collapsing is disabled, the checkbox is still not being toggled.

Comment: Well my friend. Sometimes kendo sucks so much. I have tried something here but could not achieve what you want. It's so wierd what that widget does, that I could no realize what really happens there. Could not do it with a custom click event in the input neither with css z-index. Nothing. I suggest you to post it in their forums and let they handle their own bs.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Thanks for the suggestion, but I am using Kendo UI Core, and on their forums it says, "You can participate in these forums only if you have a trial or commercial license", and that "Community questions can be directed to the "kendo-ui" StackOverflow category". So, given that I don't have a license with kendo-ui, for now this is the most appropriate place to be asking this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a workaround by just not using a checkbox. Instead of checkboxes I used a Kendo mobile switch and was able to get the switch to toggle and the panel bar not expand or collapse.

Below is the modified snippet. Items that changed are the `panelBarTemplate`, the functions inside of the `dataBound` configuration, and the css files for Kendo mobile were added.

```js
const panelBarTemplate = `
    <div>
        <span>#: item.text #</span>
        <input type='checkbox'
            id=#: item.id #
            # var ItemCheckboxClass = "my-checkbox" #
            # if (item.items) { ItemCheckboxClass = "my-checkbox expandable-item" } #
            class="#= ItemCheckboxClass #"
            # if (item.isVisible) { #checked='checked'# } # />
    </div>
`;

var canExpandCollapse = true;

$('#side-bar-panel').kendoPanelBar({
  template: panelBarTemplate,
  dataSource: [{
    text: 'Main 1',
    id: 'Main1',
    isVisible: true,
    expanded: true,
    items: [{
      text: 'Sub 1',
      id: 'Sub1',
      isVisible: true
    }, {
      text: 'Sub 2',
      id: 'Sub2',
      isVisible: false
    }]
  }],
  dataBound: function() {
    //initialize mobile switch if not already initialized.
    $('.my-checkbox').each(function(index, item) {
      let mobileSwitch = $(item);
      let mobileSwitchData = mobileSwitch.data('kendoMobileSwitch');
      if (!mobileSwitchData) {
        mobileSwitch.kendoMobileSwitch();
      }
    });

    //disable expanding and collapsing when clicking on a mobile switch
    //that is attached to an expandable panel.
    $('.expandable-item').siblings('.k-switch-container').click(function() {
      canExpandCollapse = false;
    });
  },
  expand: cancelExpandCollapse,
  collapse: cancelExpandCollapse
});

function cancelExpandCollapse(e) {
  if (!canExpandCollapse) {
    e.preventDefault();
    canExpandCollapse = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.flat.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.flat.mobile.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<ul id="side-bar-panel">
</ul>
```